# Best way to test the difference in means for Tweedie distributions?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, bootstrap, permutation-test, tweedie-distribution

What is the best way to test the difference in means for two samples of data that follow a Tweedie distribution? 
(zero inflated, tweedie power parameter ~1.7)

The data represents the number of purchases made by users on an online website, where most visitors don’t make a purchase, hence the zeroes.

I would like to calculate the p-value and confidence intervals.

Is a t-test appropriate? How about a permutation test or bootstrapping?

My data is very large (several million users), so a method that would be computationally efficient would be desirable, although I don’t mind computation intensive processing if it would result in more sensitivity/accuracy.